# GCM in android crashing due to device missing google packages

Tags: java, android, crash, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM in my android application and it is working fine most of the time.
However it crashed on a few devices, namely a Motorola device and a Lenovo device.

here the part of the crash log from the Motorola device:

```
01-26 03:21:33.701: E/AndroidRuntime(5832): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-130

01-26 03:21:33.701: E/AndroidRuntime(5832): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf

01-26 03:21:33.701: E/AndroidRuntime(5832):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(GCMRegistrar.java:98)
```

After some research, it appears that some device doesnt have the package `com.google.android.gsf`

So my question is.. what devices doesnt support it? Is there a list of devices that doesnt have the google packages required for gcm?

thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using the emulator for built? if so is it the Google API emulator? if not that's your problem .

Comment: It crashed on actual devices, namely a motorola device and a lenovo device. The other ones such as nexus 4, galaxy s3, s4 all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Google Play Services library instead on the deprecated library that contains `GCMRegistrar`. This way your app wouldn't need the `com.google.android.gsf` package at all.

Comment: Are you referring to Google Cloud Messaging? http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html
The thing is I want to use certain functions in the deprecated GCMRegistrar such as checkManifest, but they are not in the new GoogleCloudMessaging library.

Comment: @user1610613 Yes, I'm referring to GoogleCloudMessaging class. If you want to use methods of the deprecated GCMRegistrar, you can copy the source of the relevant methods (such as checkManifest) to your application. There is no need to use the deprecated registration method. Google recommend to use the new registration via Google Play Services.